# Defining Drawable Shape with in JAVA code

Tags: android, shapes

Hi
Can I define this shape without using xml code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#34342C" android:endColor="#848486"
    android:angle="90" />
<padding android:left="7dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="7dp"
    android:bottom="5dp" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

- use a [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html) to draw your rectangle with the [padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) you require
- using a [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) with the appropriate [color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColor%28int%29) and [stroke width](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth%28float%29)
- using a [Linear gradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html) and adding this to the Paint as a [shader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setShader%28android.graphics.Shader%29)