# Is it possible to create shape in android code

Tags: android, drawable, xml-drawable

I know I can define this in code but is it possible to define this kind of thing in code?

I want to create a shape and the values of the shape(["rectangle" | "oval" | "line" | "ring"]) need to be dependent from the code(user input).

Can this be done in code ? how can I do this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape=["rectangle" | "oval" | "line" | "ring"] >
    <corners
        android:radius="integer"
        android:topLeftRadius="integer"
        android:topRightRadius="integer"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="integer"
        android:bottomRightRadius="integer" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="integer"
        android:centerX="integer"
        android:centerY="integer"
        android:centerColor="integer"
        android:endColor="color"
        android:gradientRadius="integer"
        android:startColor="color"
        android:type=["linear" | "radial" | "sweep"]
        android:usesLevel=["true" | "false"] />
    <padding
        android:left="integer"
        android:top="integer"
        android:right="integer"
        android:bottom="integer" />
    <size
        android:width="integer"
        android:height="integer" />
    <solid
        android:color="color" />
    <stroke
        android:width="integer"
        android:color="color"
        android:dashWidth="integer"
        android:dashGap="integer" />
</shape>
```

Comment: please look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205354/defining-drawable-shape-with-in-java-code

Answer (score 3):

A shape drawable has an associated class [`ShapeDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html) that you could use to construct the shape in code.