# Define selector in code

Tags: android

I have the following selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00000" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Which I want to define in code. I have managed to come as far as this:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();

float[] roundedCorner = new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
float[] innerRoundedCorner = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
RectF inset = new RectF(5, 5, 5, 5);
RoundRectShape round = new RoundRectShape(roundedCorner, inset, innerRoundedCorner);        

ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(round);     
shape.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);

states.addState(new int[] {}, shape);

button.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
```

This gives me a button with a white edge, but I unable to set the button background color.
How is this achieved in code?

Comment: Why don't you use standard Android states codes from `android.R.attr.state_XXX`?

Comment: And also Is it correct to set `shape` object instead of `states` object as BackgroundDrawable?

Comment: @teoREtik The android.R.attr.state only defines for which state you are setting the Drawable, I want to be able to change colors in code according to some condition. So I need a way to draw in code.

Comment: @teoREtik the code is correct and it works. setBackgroundDrawable will  accept both a Shape and a State parameter. Changed the parameter to states for completness.

Answer (score 2):

RoundRectShape can accept null instead on RectF, then you will have a filled shape.
In addition, when you are using states, you can specify attributes as in selector: state_pressed, state_single etc.

Try this code:

```
private static StateListDrawable getStateListDrawable(int color, Context context) {
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();

    float[] roundedCorner = new float[]{4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
    float[] innerRoundedCorner = new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    RoundRectShape roundedShape = new RoundRectShape(roundedCorner, null, innerRoundedCorner);

    ShapeDrawable pressedDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(roundedShape);
    pressedDrawable.getPaint().setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_bg));
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, pressedDrawable);

    ShapeDrawable normalDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(roundedShape);
    normalDrawable.getPaint().setColor(context.getResources().getColor(color));
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{}, normalDrawable);

    return stateListDrawable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();

    float[] roundedCorner = new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
    float[] innerRoundedCorner = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    RectF inset = new RectF(0, 0, 0, 0);

    RoundRectShape round = new RoundRectShape(roundedCorner, inset, innerRoundedCorner);        
    LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 100, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, TileMode.REPEAT);

    ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(round);
    shape.getPaint().setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    //shape.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    shape.getPaint().setShader(lg);

    states.addState(new int[] {}, shape);

    button.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
```

as you define the inset object of the RectF which was add in the RoundRectShape pass the 0 value you got the complete RoundRectShape

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6205354/760489) post

Comment: The following code will not produce an edge around the shape. I want the edge to be a different color than the inner color.