# Custom Background Shape of Button via Code

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-custom-drawable

I have managed to create a custom button background shape via XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="24dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="24dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="24dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

But I am wondering what is the Java code equivalent to that? Any guides please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot more verbose to do it in Java, but here are the things you would need to do.

- Create a `new StateListDrawable()`
- For each state:

  - Create a `new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(...))`. I don't recall exactly how the constructor args work, but you can experiment.
  - Use `shapeDrawable.getPaint()` to obtain its Paint object and make modifications. You'll probably use `setColor()`, `setStyle()`, and `setStrokeWidth()`.
  - Construct a state set. This is an array of integers composed of various android state attributes, like `android.R.attr.state_pressed`, for the state you want.
  - Call `stateListDrawable.addState(stateSet, shapeDrawable)`. You can use `StateSet.NOTHING` (or an empty int[]) for the default state. Make sure you add them in the order they would appear in XML.

Something like this:

```
StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
Shape roundRect = new RoundRectShape(...);
// Add states in order. I'll just demonstrate one.
ShapeDrawable pressed = new ShapeDrawable(roundRect);
Paint paint = pressed.getPaint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(10f); // this is in pixels, you'll have to convert to dp yourself
int[] pressedState = { android.R.attr.state_pressed };
stateListDrawable.addState(pressedState, pressed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle button states like this:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_pressed));
    states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused }, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_focused));
    states.addState(new int[] {}, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_normal));
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
```

See this sample for reference:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, getSelectedBackground());
    states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused }, getSelectedBackground());
    states.addState(new int[] {}, getNormalBackground());
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(states);

private ShapeDrawable getNormalBackground() {

    int r = 10;
    float[] outerR = new float[] { r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r };
    RoundRectShape rr = new RoundRectShape(outerR, null, null);
    ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(rr);
    drawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.GRAY);

    return drawable;

}

private ShapeDrawable getSelectedBackground() {

    float[] outerR2 = new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
    RectF inset2 = new RectF(3, 3, 3, 3);
    float[] innerR2 = new float[] { 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0 };
    ShapeDrawable sh2 = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(outerR2, inset2, innerR2));
    return sh2;

}
```

Check this once [Defining Drawable Shape with in JAVA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205354/defining-drawable-shape-with-in-java-code)